# How to delete an element from an array - Javascript P5

Tags: javascript, p5.js

This is the way I add an element to my array

`assets.push(house_location + " " + "Cost" + " " + cost + " " + "Downpay"+ " " + downpay)`

Now I'm looking for a way to delete that same specific element from my array. Does someone know the code for this? So basically, the opposite of array.push

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is the [splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) method.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove the last item you pushed, use [assets.pop()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/pop). If you want to remove that exact item like you said, you could do something like this:

```js
assets.filter(d => d !== house_location + " " + "Cost" + " " + cost + " " + "Downpay"+ " " + downpay)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you are looking for these methods.

```js
Array.shift() // Removes the first item from an array, and then returns the item removed.
Array.pop() // Removes the last item from an array, and then returns the item removed.
Array.splice() // I really can't be bothered to explain this one, so look at the link below.
```

The [splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) method.